# Maven dependencies are not exported with classpath?

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, classpath, google-eclipse-plugin

I have a `GWT` project and defined dependencies with `Maven`.

I do not use maven itself to compile and deploy, but the `Eclipse Google Plugin` for `GAE` Google App Engine.
Everything works fine so for, except for server-side code that makes use of some dependencies defined with maven.

For example, I both use `Google Guava` on client and server side.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The client side dependency is somehow correctly resolved, probably by using this statement in the gwt module:

```
 <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

BUT on the serverside classes, I constantly get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` Exceptions, which probably mean the library cannot be found serverside.

I could fix it manually by copying all neccessary libraries to `WEB-INF/lib`, which resolves these errors. But is there any other way not having to copy these libs manually to my war folder?

I thought I could define the classpath assemblies to export the maven dependencies like:

But that does not change anything. What could I do?

Exception:

```
An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:323)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:691)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_ServerCustomFieldSerializerBase.deserialize(Collection_ServerCustomFieldSerializerBase.java:38)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserialize(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:40)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserializeInstance(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.deserializeInstance(ArrayList_ServerCustomFieldSerializer.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:859)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:807)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:878)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:662)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.readObject(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:567)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader$ValueReader$8.readValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:312)
    ... 40 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 72 more

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.instantiate(IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.java:16)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.create(IncompatibleRemoteServiceException_FieldSerializer.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Is this a WAR deployment?  If so, can you check the libs to see if the needed JAR dependencies are there?  If they are not, you can instruct Maven to include them in the WAR when it builds it by setting the scope, I believe.

Comment: yes this is a WAR deployment, and the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder only contains either manual copied libraries and the ones added automatically by GWT nature: `gwt-servlet`, `appengine-apis`, etc. Which scope should I apply where to try this?

Comment: By default, I think Maven uses compile scope.  The scopes are described here:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

I would recommend yoy read through this as well:  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven, https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5033 and http://pgt.de/2012/12/19/gpe-eclipse-and-maven-never-ending-story-done/

Put simply: this is the expected behavior, you have to run `mvn package` (or `mvn compile  war:exploded` or something similar) every time you change a dependency.

If you feel like it should be changed, the issue tracker for the Google Plugin for Eclipse is at https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: Probably that's the right answer if someone uses maven to deploy. In my case, I just use maven for dependency management, and the eclipse plugin itself to deploy. After having installed `m2e-wtp` (which I did not have so far), the libs from maven are all copied to /lib folder as expected.